# SonarQube not ignoring C++ code with // NOSONAR

Tags: sonarqube

We're using `SonarQube 5.3`. One of the developers told that SonarQube is *not* ignoring a false positive although he marked it with `// NOSONAR` in source code.

[image: SonarQube not ignoring NOSONAR]

In Java it's working fine. Is there another way for C++? We're using `cppcheck` plugin.

PS: I know the way marking it as false positive via UI. But it would be good to mark it right in the source code.

Comment: The problem is not on SonarQube itself. You should open an issue on the Cxx SonarQube plugin => https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx

Comment: https://github.com/SonarOpenCommunity/sonar-cxx/issues/885

Comment: I have the same problem with the Sonarlint plug-in in VSCode, and it is 2023. From what I read they don’t want to support this way of disabling warning so you use their system. (?)